# C# .Net Form won't draw if mouse is on image which has a tooltip

Tags: c#, forms, tooltip, picturebox

I have a form with an picturebox on it and picturebox have tooltip. Problem is when form loads and mouse is over image, form wont draw - see image. When mouse leaves picturebox then everything is ok.

## Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testTooltip
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(toolTip1.Active)
            toolTip1.Show(e.X + " " + e.Y, this, e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(this);
        }
    }
}
```

## Form1.designer.cs

```
namespace testTooltip
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // toolTip1
            // 
            this.toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 5000;
            this.toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
            this.toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Test";
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::testTooltip.Properties.Resources.screen000;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 12);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 429);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseLeave);
            this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(730, 457);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    }
}
```

here is preview
http://www.bildites.lv/images/1iftt7hxbqloz0vw949.png
and this is when mouse leaves picturebox
http://www.bildites.lv/images/tp47375fpl6q3oguh6e.png

Comment: Have you tried it without the tooltip, to see if that is causing the problem?

Comment: One glaring obvious mistake: set the tooltip's OwnerDraw property back to False.  Or actually implement the Draw event.

Comment: without tooltip it works fine, but i need that tooltip and setting OwnerDraw property to False doesnt fix anything, it only makes tooltip flickering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try just with a `Label` control instead of `ToolTip`.

Comment: tried with label - label1.Location = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(e.Location); works fine but its far away from mouse location and each time random
label1.Location = e.Location; same problem as tooltip

Comment: Assuming my label is named lblTooltip and within your event handler: `lblTooltip.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y); lblTooltip.Text = e.X + " " + e.Y;`

Comment: This way you are not going to suffer the strange behavior mentioned in your post, happening when when the mouse is directly over the picturebox when the form is about to be shown, causing the main picturebox to not be shown.